# Providing a Hyper-V virtual machine access to USB devices

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, backtrack

I have Backtrack hosted on a Hyper-V virtual machine, and I want to give it access to my USB WiFi dongle, not just access to the network, but actually access to the hardware itself so I can scan for WiFi networks etc.

In the past I have used VirtualBox, and this has been relatively painless, but I have Windows 8.1 Pro, so thought I would give Hyper-V a go.

With the device enabled under "Network Connections" I the following error:

> Failed while adding virtual Ethernet switch connections. The Requested resource is in use.

[image: Enabled]

When it's disabled, I get this error instead:

> Failed while adding virtual Ethernet switch connections. Adapter not enabled or not functional.

[image: Disabled]

Is this possible, or do I need to head back to VirtualBox?

Comment: Why are you messing around in the Virtual Switch manager if you want to attach a USB device to your VM?

Comment: @MichaelHampton This is my first time using Hyper-V, what should I be messing around with to attach a USB device? And to answer your question, I thought you may be able to expose the WiFi hardware directly to the VM, regardless of whether it was USB/PCI etc

Comment: Oh... a simple Google search turned up the fact that Hyper-V doesn't support attaching USB devices directly to virtual machines at all.

Comment: Really? I'm seeing lots of stuff about [Enhanced Session Mode](http://www.msserverpro.com/support-for-usb-access-in-windows-server-2012-r2-hyper-v-through-microsofts-new-virtual-machine-enhanced-session-mode/) which apparantly is for exactly this.

Answer (score 4):

Hyper-V does not support USB redirection. VMWare ESXi does from v4.1.

I personally needed USB redirection and had to use a commercial USB redirection software [USB Over Network](http://www.usb-over-network.com/usb-over-network.html.). This software works by redirecting the USB connection from the host machine (Windows 8.1) to the client (VM) over TCP/IP

Answer (score 1):

Generally, Hyper-V does not support USB redirection.

The "Enhanced Session Mode" stuff does RDP-like sharing of resources over the internal VMBus. The only combinations of OSes are Windows Server 2012 R2 on the host and **Windows Server 2012 R2 or Windows 8.1** on the guest (probably due to how it's implemented).